# Unable to download XML file on server, works fine on other

Tags: php

I have had an application running successfully for a couple months that relies on a cron job to get an xml feed of air pollution statistics. Since January it has run without error, but this morning from 7:00 it has not read the data. The relevant code is as follows:

```
<?php
define('FEED_URL', 'http://www.beijingaqifeed.com/BeijingAQI/BeijingAir.xml');
$contents = file_get_contents(FEED_URL);
if ($contents === false) echo "READ FAILED";
echo "FILE_GET_CONTENTS SIZE IS " . strlen($contents) . "<br>\n";
```

If I run this on my machine at home, it works:

```
FILE_GET_CONTENTS SIZE IS 21538
```

If it runs on my server it does not:

```
FILE_GET_CONTENTS SIZE IS 0
```

I have confirmed with support at the server site that they can browse the url and see the xml data, so there is no firewall or anything blocking this. And, as I say, this has worked successfully over 1000 times (as measured by entries in my database) until this morning, and now it always fails. I have no connection at the data supplier so I can't investigate from their side.

Can anyone suggest why this started failing, and what I could try doing? I have tried fread() and file(), with the same results.

Thanks...

(I have checked allow_url_fopen is turned on)

Comment: check configuration of file_get_contents in the server. allow_url_fopen = On
needs to be set in php.ini.

Comment: What happens if you try to download the file using `curl` or `wget` from the CLI?

Comment: Check with your host to see if they updated any software that may effect this like PHP versions/settings. If nothing has changed on your side at all they something did on the other side and you will have to write something new to compensate for the changes.

Comment: The host says they haven't changed anything, and I looked over phpinfo, and didn't see anything that looked wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First I thought it would be permissions but, that isn't the case.

Try changing server, maybe your IP is blocked or something?

```
<?php
function download($website){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    $retValue = curl_exec($ch);          
    curl_close($ch);
    return $retValue;
}

$XML = download('http://www.beijingaqifeed.com/BeijingAQI/BeijingAir.xml');
var_dump($XML);
```

Perform:

`wget http://www.beijingaqifeed.com/BeijingAQI/BeijingAir.xml` via SSH (if possible) and see the response.

Comment: I have edited my answer.. Check the next instructions. And let me know what you get.

Comment: It may not be permission issue.. else it would print `READ FAILED`

Comment: Good thought. I can't ssh, but I did do an exec from php, and the file ended up empty 

    exec("wget -O /home/rwy/aqi.xml http://www.beijingaqifeed.com/BeijingAQI/BeijingAir.xml");

Comment: Hmmm in that case, it is your hosting provider. Change it.

Comment: I also tried changing the url, both to http://yahoo.com and to a sample xml file I found online (http://www.simplyhired.com/c/add-jobs/example-feed.xml), and both worked - it is just this file which is failing.

Comment: Script is fine. I tried both on my machine. Check your XML provider, maybe they have some issues with this particular IP or Country or Provider.

Answer (score 0):

It is in this case probaly something on server blocking Your PHP , might be OS update , or something like that. In past I had similar problems , but , mines was about unkillable daemon , linked with cron job , so , me and support team had big headaches of turning it off. In this case , this is crucial for further investigation , this line: FILE_GET_CONTENTS SIZE IS 21538 , if someone could obtain it and read it , there's the catch. This answer might not be helpful at all , but , as I stated , that error line is key.

Odd , I've just checked XML URL , and it works , normally , as it should.

Comment: I can get the file either in my browser, or from the same php code run on my local machine. The only thing that might be odd is there are 3 characters at the front of the code. I am not sure whether they were there before. They are not BOM, I wonder if they could be messing things up. The file starts out "\357\273\277<?xml version...".

Comment: It may sound stupid , but , how it would be if removing them helps ?

Comment: I can't remove them from the feed, and since I am getting a strlen of 0 I can't remove them afterwards. I wonder if I could do a binary read?

Answer (score 0):

probably permission issue. Try to add the following after `file_get_contents` to see their response

```
if (!empty($http_response_header))
{
  var_dump($http_response_header); 
  //to see what tou get back
}
```

Comment: I tried it on my machine... It is working flawless. There is no specific permission issue.

Comment: I asked him to use cURL... because even my server could do that... So works on 2 machines but not on one server..!

Comment: A blocked IP is also a permission issue.

Comment: Blocked IP  / 404 / 500 / 301 / etc would print : READ FAILED . I just checked his source code...

Comment: $http_response_header is NULL

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that there is 500 error , so - their side. Depends what do they use , but many admins (like me) avoid to point out server errors , replacing them with useless comments or simply , by removing them. This is done to prevent intruders , as error code could stick attacker to server under my administration , and if it gets down - my fault.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a final answer, but it clarifies things somewhat. I tried uploading the file to the server and reading it from there the same way (http:/young-0/testfile.xml) and it succeeded. Then I tried getting "http://www.beijingaqifeed.com" from the server - and that failed. So the bom was a red herring, the connection is being blocked either by my provider (who says it is not them) or the site is refusing connections from my server - thanks to everyone who helped.

For now I have returned to using the twitter feed, which is far less reliable but does have the advantage that I am able to read it.